# Make GStreamer pipeline drop erroneous buffers

Tags: gstreamer, crc, gstreamer-1.0

My pipeline splits in the middle to be sent over an unreliable connection. This results in some buffers having bit errors that break the pipeline if I do not account for them. To solve this, I have an `appsink` that parses buffers for their critical information (timestamps, duration, data, and data size), serializes them, and then sends that over the unreliable channel with a CRC. If the receiving pipeline reads a buffer from the unreliable channel and detect a bit error with the CRC, the buffer is dropped. Most decoders are able to recover fine from a dropped buffer, aside from some temporary visual artifacts.

Is there a GStreamer plugin that does this automatically? I looked into the GDPPay and GDPDepay plugins which appeared to meet my needs due to there serialization of buffers and inclusion of CRC's for their header and payload, however the plugin assumes that the data is being sent over a reliable channel (why this assumption and the inclusion of CRCs, I do not know).

I am tempted to take the time to make a plugin/make a pull request to the GDP plugins that just drop bad buffers instead of pausing the pipeline with a GST_FLOW_ERROR.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Ideally it would also be tolerant to either pipeline crashing/restarting. (The plugin also expects the Caps filter information to be the first buffer sent, which in my case I do not need to send as I have a fixed purpose and can hard-code both ends to know what to expect. This is only a problem if the receiver restarts and the sender is already sending data, but the receiver will not get the data because it is waiting for the Caps data that the sender already sent.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When faced with similar issue (but for `GstEvents`), I used [GstProbe](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/additional/design/probes.html?gi-language=c). You'll probably need to install it for `GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER` and return `GST_PAD_PROBE_DROP` for the buffers that doesn't satisfy your conditions. It is easier than defining a plugin and definitely it is easier to modify (`GstProbe` can be created and handled from the code, so changing the dropping logic is easier). Caveat: I haven't done it for the buffers, but it should be doable.

Let me know if it worked!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I just read up on GstProbes and this certainly seems like the way to go if I were to do things over again. Given the limited scope of what I am working on I, I am just sticking with the hacky external CRC solution, but will certainly keep in mind GstProbes for the future.